# Does Text-To-Speech need OAuth consent screen?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to use Text-To-Speech from Google API but do I must add OAuth consent screen or not important?

It's for apps on phones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application is meant to be used by less than 100 users, it doesn't use any user data or fits any of the other scenarios mentioned on the [Exceptions to verification requirements](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#exceptions-ver-reqts:%7E:text=Exceptions%20to%20verification%20requirements,-Exceptions) section of the OAuth API verification documentation then it shouldn't undergo the App Verification process.

Now, the [Cloud Text-to-Speech API](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#texttospeech) itself uses the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` scope which is considered a sensitive scope that requires verification.  In general if you see that a little lock icon shows up when adding the scope of the relevant API that will mean that the app will require to go through the verification process:

[image]

You'll notice that after adding that scope to your OAuth consent screen some warnings will pop up on your Cloud Console suggesting to go through the app verification process:

[image]

So if you don't fit any of the criteria mentioned on the previous link shared your application would need to go through the verification process.